# How can I apply MVC for frontend development using any Javascript Framework ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js, frontend

Where is the the Model data is stored ? What things would represent Model, View and Controller to be specific ?

Answer (score 1):

Model is where the application’s data objects are stored. The model doesn’t know anything about views and controllers. When a model changes, typically it will notify its observers that a change has occurred. This could be a database, text file or other forms of storage.

View is what's presented to the users and how users interact with the app. The view is made with HTML, CSS, JavaScript and often templates.

The controller is the decision maker and the glue between the model and view. The controller updates the view when the model changes. It also adds event listeners to the view and updates the model when the user manipulates the view.